# Best way to destructuring inside react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have seen people use destructuring like this in functional components in react.

```
const InputGroup = ({
  name,
  placeholder,
  value
}) => (
```

Rather than doing this, my preferred way is,

```
 const InputGroup = props => {
      const { name, placeholder, value } = props
}
```

which is the better way? I feel like the second approach is more readable but the first approach is more cleaner.

Comment: A benefit of the first pattern is that the typescript compiler can infer the "shape" of props, which means that editors like vscode can provide intellisense hints for those props. This even works when you're writing Javascript. This is enough of a benefit to make me choose the first pattern, but it's a small difference

Comment: If you work on a team, I find it's best to use the most commonly understood way. In this case, I think your preferred way is the way to go. For personal projects touched only by me, I prefer the first approach, because I get to avoid an extra `const` declaration.

Comment: They are almost exactly the same and require the same js knowledge for the reader to understand. I see no difference here, just choose the convention that fit your taste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no practical difference in production.

The difference is that if `props` object is used, it can be debugged. Otherwise only destructured props are available in function scope.

This is not a problem if ES5 target is in use because an arrow is transpiled to regular function which has `arguments` object that can be examined in debugger.

It's also beneficial to consistently destructure `props` object for maintenance purposes. This way functional components can be converted to class components and vice versa without changing existing lines in function body:

```
const InputGroup = props => {
  const { name, placeholder, value } = props;
  ...
}
```

and

```
class InputGroup extends Component {
  render() {
   const { props } = this;
   const { name, placeholder, value } = props;
   ...
  }
}
```

Another flavour of destructuring is to not destructure `props` at all because of naming collisions, primarily between props and state; both can contain identically named entities:

```
const InputGroup = props => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(...);

  return <p>{state.name || props.name}</p>;
}
```

Renaming them during destructuring or allowing only one of them to be destructured would result in inconsistent code style.

Answer (score 1):

No one of them is better.
Second way is impossible to implement in functional components, because you can not create consts in them.
First way is nice to read when you will get more experience with writing code in react.

Comment: Being able to reassign function arguments doesn't prevent you from writing functional components. The two concepts aren't related as far as I can tell. Still, if you value `const` variables that's a small benefit of the second pattern